# Android custom SharedPreferences implementation to persist to database?

Tags: android

I am attempting to use a custom implementation of the `SharedPreferences` interface to persist an application's preferences to a database (instead of the default XML).

Why? I'd like to use the convenience of `PreferenceActivity` to construct the UI but this app will be used on multiple devices so the preferences a user sets need to persist across devices.

So.. I've got the implementation written, but can't figure out how to associate a particular SharedPreference with a `PreferenceActivity`. I know that uses `getSharedPreferences()`, but how can I override that? Can i register my `SharedPreferences` somehow? I did not see anything in the API to do this.

Or ... if I'm going about this all wrong please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been investigating this question some time ago. For a different reason though.

What I found is that `PreferenceActivity` is highly coupled with `PreferenceManager` and it uses `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` deep inside to get `SharedPreference` instance. And there is no way to either substitute custom `PreferenceManager` or `SharedPreference` instance inside `PrefernceActivity`.

I found that Preference framework is inflexible and it's quite hard to extend or change default behaviors, and sometimes its even impossible. But my guess is that designers of this this framework had "ease of use" as their top priority, not extendability and flexibility. Which is understandable.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Thanks for the reply. I suppose I'll have to just write my own preferences screen then.

Comment: You can just copy the code over and modify it to your needs (just keep original package name): http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java&q=PreferenceActivity&exact_package=android&type=cs

Comment: I suppose I could have done that. Instead I set a OnPreferenceChangeListener for each Preference in the PreferenceActivity. When called it sets the preference in a separate data structure that is saved to the database when the user logs out.

Comment: Don't forget to call `setPersistent(false)` then (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setPersistent%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

After some research and having that very particular need, there is a "simple" solution.

One will need to override both SharedPreferences and Editor to provides its own implementation, then every Preferences must also be extended to override the various persistXXX() and getPersistedXXX() methods.

For example, the CheckBoxPreference can override persistBoolean and getPersistedBoolean to do the trick.

Sadly it seems impossible to simply extendsthe PreferenceManager class to then only override getPreferenceManager() in each Preference classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy work-around: just set all preferences to `persistent="false"` (either via XML or via `preference.setPersistent(false)` in the code).  Then, setup `OnPreferenceChangeListener`'s to get notified when preferences are changed and let the handler store the values in some custom database.

Here is my code:

```
Preference preference = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref1));
Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener changeListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            preference.setSummary((String)value + " something");

            // store value in custom database
            store((String)value);

            return true;
        }
    };
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);
    // update preference from custom database (once)
    changeListener.onPreferenceChange(preference, getValueFromDatabase());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on preferences which are stored on a Bluetooth device. My solution is to override the getSharedPreferences method of my Activity:

```
@Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode) {
    return new MySharedPreferences(this);
}
```

MySharedPreference is my implementation of the android.content.SharedPreferences interface. You must also implement it's inner classes. In the MySharedPreference constructer the activity is passed as parameter and stored in a member variable