# How to force PreferenceActivity to deal with my SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store my data across all `Activities` within my application. I get access to it like this:

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
```

I've implemented `PreferenceActivity` so users can change values through it but it happens it reads/writes data not to "MyPrefs" but to:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Which is a bit unexpected for me. Is that possible to force `PreferenceActivity` to deal with my "MyPrefs" preferences? And what is the point to have several preferences within single application? Thank you.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045417/android-custom-sharedpreferences-implementation-to-persist-to-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get access to it like this

That's fine, so long as you weren't planning on using `PreferenceActivity`.

> I've implemented PreferenceActivity so users can change values through it

Oops.

Also, get rid of `getApplicationContext()` there, unless you have a specific reason for using the `Application` rather than the activity/service/whatever. Only use the `Application` object when you have to and you know why you have to.

> Is that possible to force PreferenceActivity to deal with my "MyPrefs" preferences?

Not readily. Unless you have some specific reason to invent your own `SharedPreferences` file, I'd use the default one.

> And what is the point to have several preferences within single application?

You might have a reusable library or component want to store stuff in `SharedPreferences`, and that might have its own file so as not to mess up any preferences from the hosting application. That being said, multiple preference files is not typically needed.

Comment: `PreferenceActivity`'s `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName()` does the trick

Answer (score 15):

It is possible and simple. This worked for me

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("MyPrefs");
        //getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. This technique also works if you're using a `PreferenceFragment`

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend just using  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) everywhere, which is the same as what the preference activity is using. But if you need to stick with your current setup then a hacky solution (but the only one I know of) is to override getSharedPreferences to return what you want.

```
@Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
    return super.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", mode);
}
```